# Swarmplot in seaborn where each point has a different colour

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to use seaborn to get a swarmplot. A simplified example is given below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn
import pandas
import numpy as np

acceptance = np.array([10, 11, 20, 30, 9, 40, 15])

plt.figure()

dfa = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'acceptance (%)': acceptance,
})

seaborn.swarmplot(data=dfa)

plt.show()
```

I'm trying to update this so that seaborn gives each point a different colour, but I can't seem to find a combination of arguments that makes this work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's pass `hue`:

```
sns.swarmplot(data=dfa, x=np.ones(len(dfa)), 
              y='acceptance (%)', 
              hue=np.arange(len(dfa)))

# remove legend if necessary
# plt.legend().remove()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Uncomment the `plt.legend()...` line in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried adding an array in the dataframe earlier, and then naming that array as hue, but that didn't work. Any ideas why?